# matplotlib embed figures in auto generated html

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

I want to embed a figure generated by python matplotlib into a html file with other content. Is that possible?

What I have thought is saving figures as png file and then use `<img>` tag to refer to it.

Some code I was trying to use are like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
#plot sth
plt.savefig('test.png')

html = 'Some html head' + '<img src=\'test.png\'>' + 'Some more html'

with open('test.html','w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

However, this will generate two files instead of one and I don't have a server to host the png file. Is that possible to embed the figure in the html? How do I do it in python.

Thank you.

Comment: What about use a base64 image? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: Outlook IOS client does not show image which is base64 encoded in the html format email. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can write the image into a temporary file and encode it with base64 and then embed the encoded base64 image into your html. Most modern browsers will correctly render the image.

A short example modified from your code will be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64
from io import BytesIO

fig = plt.figure()
#plot sth

tmpfile = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(tmpfile, format='png')
encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')

html = 'Some html head' + '<img src=\'data:image/png;base64,{}\'>'.format(encoded) + 'Some more html'

with open('test.html','w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I found I had to do one additional step of decoding the `encoded`.

`"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{}'>".format(encoded.decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: I solved my problem by using
`encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue()).decode('utf8')`
`<img src='data:image/png;base64,{{}}'>`

Comment: Awesome answer! 

Comment: Where is the image data in this

Comment: How to  Convert matrix data into image inside HTML or else how to embedded matrix data as image in HTML

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the image using base64 encoding:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes

and then embed the encoded string in the html like so:
[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)