# Save the Matplotlib plot in html format

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

I have a plot written in matplotlib.

Currently I saved that plot in pdf ,but i also want to save it in .html format for better visualization.

I am not aware of any html stuff , so need inputs here

Below is my code:

```
     output_file = config["output_dir"] / "report.pdf"
     with PdfPages(output_file) as pdf:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, constrained_layout = True)
        for x in new_hpg_groupdf:
            ax[0].plot(x[1]['iTOW'] , x[1]['ionoEst'] , label=f"{satellite} {x[0][1]}")
            ax[0].set_ylabel("Iono Estimation (TECU)")
            ax[0].set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
            ax[0].grid(True)
            ax[0].legend(fontsize=4 , loc='upper left' , bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02])
            ax[0].set_title('Iono Estimation Output')

            ax[1].plot(x[1]['iTOW'] , x[1]['ionoEstAcc'] , label=f"{satellite} {x[0][1]}")
            ax[1].set_ylabel("Iono Accuracy (TECU)")
            ax[1].set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
            ax[1].grid(True)
            ax[1].legend(fontsize=4 , loc='upper left' , bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02])
            ax[1].set_title('Iono Estimation Accuracy Output')
        
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()
```

Comment: This might help: [Dynamically serving a matplotlib image to the web using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824522/dynamically-serving-a-matplotlib-image-to-the-web-using-python)

Comment: Or maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48717971/12890458?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [MPLD3](https://mpld3.github.io/). Just import that library and run `mpld3.show()` instead of the usual `plt.show()` when you want to see your plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3

# some fake data
new_hpg_groupdf = [
    [[0, 1], {'iTOW': [0, 4, 8, 10, 12], 'ionoEst': [20, 25, 19, 17, 21], 'ionoEstAcc': [1, 2, -3, 2, 3]}],
    [[0, 2], {'iTOW': [0, 8, 10, 12], 'ionoEst': [60, 65, 59, 61], 'ionoEstAcc': [-2, -1, 2, 0]}],
    [[0, 3], {'iTOW': [0, 2, 4, 10, 12], 'ionoEst': [40, 43, 39, 45, 41], 'ionoEstAcc': [3, 2, -3, -2, 3]}]
]

satellite = 'S'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, constrained_layout = True)
for x in new_hpg_groupdf:
    ax[0].plot(x[1]['iTOW'] , x[1]['ionoEst'] , label=f"{satellite} {x[0][1]}")
    ax[0].set_ylabel("Iono Estimation (TECU)")
    ax[0].set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
    ax[0].grid(True)
    ax[0].legend(fontsize=4 , loc='upper left' , bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02])
    ax[0].set_title('Iono Estimation Output')

    ax[1].plot(x[1]['iTOW'] , x[1]['ionoEstAcc'] , label=f"{satellite} {x[0][1]}")
    ax[1].set_ylabel("Iono Accuracy (TECU)")
    ax[1].set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
    ax[1].grid(True)
    ax[1].legend(fontsize=4 , loc='upper left' , bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02])
    ax[1].set_title('Iono Estimation Accuracy Output')

mpld3.show()
```

The code will produce an HTML-page with the following image:

[image]

For comparison, this is how the same plot looks like, when showing it with `plt.show`:

[image]

Apparently, this plot looks better, although it differs from the "mpld3 one" not so much. However, the differences can get bigger when you want to make somewhat fancier plots, e.g. having [dark background](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html#sphx-glr-gallery-style-sheets-dark-background-py) (`plt.style.use('dark_background')`):

[image]

This doesn't look nice due to some trouble with grid lines. The respective "plt plot" would look much better:

[image]

So it looks like with MPLD3 you will always need some additional tuning. But it's very easy to use.

Comment: This looks simple and quick ,Thanks! . I was able to save the plot , but I need to save multiple sub plots to some other working directory . I tried below code but it does not work .                                                                                                                                output_file = config["output_dir"] /                                             mpld3.save_html(fig, output_file '+' figtest.html')  .                                                 Is there a way we can save/append multipl plots using mpld3.save_html to some specified working directory

Comment: It looks like either the directory doesn't exist or its name does not contain two back slashes (I assume you are using Windows). You may want to try something like `join(output_dir, file_name)` from the `os.path` library to combine your directory name and your file name into one path. This way is going to be more general and safe. And of course the directory must be created in advance.

Comment: When I check the output_file it does print the complete path with the filename but when I pass it as an argument to mpld3.save_html it gives me an error:        output_file = config["output_dir"] / "testing.html"        
print('output_file1', output_file)        #Output: C:\test\testing.html                                   mpld3.save_html(fig,output_file)                                                                                           raise ValueError("fileobj should be a filename or a writable file")
ValueError: fileobj should be a filename or a writable file

Comment: Could you please show, how you create `config["output_dir"]`. The directory looks like an object residing in the dictionary `config`, but I need more details, e.g. the type of that object, the way the whole dictionary is created, etc.

Comment: config is a .json file , its type is <class 'dict'> and below are its contents : {
    "input_logs_dir": "C:\\test",
    "output_dir": "C:\\logs",
    "constellation": "GPS",
}

Comment: I see. So `config["output_dir"]` is a string with a Windows path to that directory. Then I would make the full path either with `output_file = os.path.join(config["output_dir"], "testing.html")` or simply with `output_file = config["output_dir"] + "\\testing.html"`

Comment: Yes I am able to get the file path with the file name in the variable output_file (C:\test\testing.html) but when I pass it to mpld3.save_html as an argument : mpld3.save_html(fig,output_file) it gives me error :                                                     raise ValueError("fileobj should be a filename or a writable file")
ValueError: fileobj should be a filename or a writable file

Comment: Also if i try output_file = config["output_dir"] + "\\testing.html" ,                                          I get below error :                                                                                                     output_file = config["output_dir"] + "\\testing.html"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

Comment: So it looks like you are not simply reading the string `output_dir` from your JSON file, but rather you are converting it to WindowsPath type. Find a way to get that string in its original state, and then everything will work.